# How to change default sort order in CKAN of search result?

Tags: python, solr, ckan

I'm using CKAN 2.6.6 currently and I have created some customized sort order based on docs here: [Sorting by custom fields on the dataset search page](http://docs.ckan.org/en/2.6/extensions/adding-custom-fields.html#sorting-by-custom-fields-on-the-dataset-search-page) However this document didn't show us how to set the default sort order from "Relevance" to other customized fields. I would like to know how can I do this without modifying the CKAN core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the function`before_search` in the [IPackageController interface](http://docs.ckan.org/en/2.6/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IPackageController) and add the `sort` parameter you want. Like so:

```
# IPackageController
    def before_search(self, search_params):
        search_params.update({
            'sort': search_params.get('sort', 'value desc')
        })
        return search_params
```

Comment: Did you mean I can create a dictionary `search_params` such that one of the key-value pair is `{'sort': 'value desc'}` and then my default sort order will be `value desc`?

Comment: Just modify it in case there is no key `sort` already. I put example code into the answer above.

Comment: It is the correct way of changing it, thanks for your advice, your answer should be accepted and acknowledged.